# Source File Changed But Page is not Changed

Tags: hottowel

I have just started my very first HotTowel SPA template project in VS 2012 and I need some help.

I was investigating the plumbing to see how it works.  I added <h1>xxx</h1> to home.html.  I then ran the project in debug mode.  No amount of browser refresh (Chrome or IE) would let me see the changed home.html.  Where did I go wrong?

However, if I go directly to `http://localhost:56447/app/views/home.html` from my browser, I do see the changed source.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try clearing browser cache yet?
[Here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en) is how to clear cache.

For development purpose, you can disable caching in chrome as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development).